# Confidence Interval question with Cars

Tags: statistics

Question: The mean lifetime expected from a model of automobile follows a normal distribution with a standard deviation of 9500km. A sample of 100 cards showed a mean lifetime of 190000km. Detrmine the margin of error at 90% confidence limit.

So we've already been given a z score (1.645) but when i'm writing out my equation, I don't know what my p value is.

Answer (score 1):

**Terminology:** *P-value* would be for a test of hypothesis. *Margin of error* and *significance level* are for a confidence interval (CI).

**Confidence interval.** A 90% CI (z-interval) for population mean lifetime $\mu$ would be of the
form

$$\bar X \pm 1.645\sigma/\sqrt{n},$$ 
where $\bar X = 190,000,\, \sigma = 9500,$ and $n=100.$ [This is a
z-interval (not a t-interval) because the *population* SD $\sigma$ is known.]

**Margin of error.** The 'margin of error' for your 90% CI is $1.645\sigma/\sqrt{n}.$